# Cannot display or render images while sending emails as html templates using spring thymleaf

Tags: spring-boot, templates, thymeleaf, email-templates

Unable to see the image rendered using spring thymleaf , were the image is located at resources/static/images/image.png

my html

```
<div class="headerFrame">
                <div class="innerFrame">
                    <img class="innerFrame" src="@{/static/images/rsilogo.png}" th:src="${springLogo}" alt="RSI"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and in my service file i set the context variables

```
Context context = new Context();
                context.setVariable("springLogo", "/static/images/rsilogo.png");
```

and also added configuration file which reads the html templates

```
public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    springTemplateEngine.addTemplateResolver(emailTemplateResolver());
    return springTemplateEngine;
}
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    emailTemplateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return emailTemplateResolver;
}
```

i'm able to see the image from browser , but while sending this template through mail(outlook) , it is not rendering the image

Comment: Try `/images/rsilogo.png` without `static`. By default spring serves static content from any of the `/static`, `/public`, `/resources`, and `/META-INF/resources` directories that are on the classpath

Comment: without static its not rendering through browser , with static it is rendering in browser , but while sending template through mail , image is not rendered

Comment: If you look at the source html of the email, what does the URL show for the image? Is it an absolute url pointing at the server where you serve the image?

Comment: no , i just used the path where the logo is located in my local